# How to print individual rows from a post header, python

Tags: python, post, http-post

This is the code that is important:

```
elif msgheader.startswith( 'POST' ):
        print "The POST msg:\n", msgheader
```

And this is the response:

```
The POST msg:
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.102:63166
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://192.168.1.102:63166
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://192.168.1.102:63166/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

comment=test
```

Now my question is how i can print out individual rows of the response like the comment field. I tried using this code but i get an error:

```
print['comment']

Exception (with type 'exceptions.TypeError'): string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this supposing you are using urllib2:

```
print msgheader.getheader('content-type')
```

With requests lib you should use:

```
print msgheader['content-type']
```